# How can I check if the user has entered a valid operand? (Python)

Tags: python, validation, while-loop, boolean, user-input

I'm writing code to implement a simple calculator in python. I'm attempting to check if a user has entered a valid operand. The code I entered is below.

```
calc = False
while calc == False:
    firstNum = 0
    operand = ''
    secondNum = 0
    firstNum = input('Please enter a number: ')
    if firstNum.isdigit() == False:
        print('Please enter a number.')
        continue
    else:
        firstNum = int(firstNum)
    operand = input('Please enter an operand (+, -, *, or /): ')
    if operand != '/' or operand != '*' or operand != '+' or operand != '-':
        print('Please enter a valid operand.')
        continue
    secondNum = input('Please enter another number: ')
    if secondNum.isdigit() == False:
        print('Please enter a number.')
        continue
    secondNum = int(secondNum)
    if secondNum == 0 and operand == '/':
        print('You cannot divide by 0. Please try again.')
        continue
    if operand == '+':
        calc = True
        print(f'{firstNum} + {secondNum} = {firstNum + secondNum}')
    elif operand == '*':
        calc = True
        print(f'{firstNum} * {secondNum} = {firstNum * secondNum}')
    elif operand == '-':
        calc = True
        print(f'{firstNum} - {secondNum} = {firstNum - secondNum}')
    else:
        calc = True
        print(f'{firstNum} / {secondNum} = {firstNum / secondNum}')
```

```
calc = False
while calc == False:
    firstNum = 0
    operand = ''
    secondNum = 0
    listOfOperands = ['+', '-', '/', '*']
    firstNum = input('Please enter a number: ')
    if firstNum.isdigit() == False:
        print('Please enter a number.')
        continue
    else:
        firstNum = int(firstNum)
    operand = input('Please enter an operand (+, -, *, or /): ')
    if operand != listOfOperands:
        print('Please enter a valid operand.')
        continue
    secondNum = input('Please enter another number: ')
    if secondNum.isdigit() == False:
        print('Please enter a number.')
        continue
    secondNum = int(secondNum)
    if secondNum == 0 and operand == '/':
        print('You cannot divide by 0. Please try again.')
        continue
    if operand == '+':
        calc = True
        print(f'{firstNum} + {secondNum} = {firstNum + secondNum}')
    elif operand == '*':
        calc = True
        print(f'{firstNum} * {secondNum} = {firstNum * secondNum}')
    elif operand == '-':
        calc = True
        print(f'{firstNum} - {secondNum} = {firstNum - secondNum}')
    else:
        calc = True
        print(f'{firstNum} / {secondNum} = {firstNum / secondNum}')
```

The current versions of the code always reject the operand and goes back to the top of the while loop. I would like to return to the top of the loop if the user didn't enter +, -, *, or / and continue through the loop if they did enter one of the four characters.

Comment: You can change all of the `or`s to `and`s in `operand != '/' or operand != '*' or operand != '+' or operand != '-'`, or better yet check for membership in a tuple of the four operands.

Comment: For your second version, you'd want to change `operand != listOfOperands` to `operand not in listOfOperands`

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly.

Comment: You're welcome. Make sure to study the difference so that you understand why the new code works but the old code didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"... I'm attempting to check if a user has entered a valid operand. ..."*

To clarify, an *"[operand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operand)"* is the quantity.  You're referring to the *"[operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(computer_programming))"*.
Hence, in *a + b*, both *a* and *b* are operands.

> *"... The current versions of the code always reject the operand and goes back to the top of the while loop. ..."*

Your *conditional-statement* is incorrect.
Using *or* would mean that any of those conditions need to be *True*.

Use *and*, instead.

```py
if operand != '/' and operand != '*' and operand != '+' and operand != '-':
```

And possibly, a more intuitive approach would be to use the *[not](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)* and *[in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations)* *operations*.

```py
if operand not in '/*+-':
```